# React: Higher Order Components: Can you can childs state

Tags: reactjs, mixins, ecmascript-5, higher-order-components

I'm trying to refactor from mixins to HOCs so I can upgrade to the newest React (I'm currently using React 13/ES5). When my component loads, the mixin is able to access a data object, `this.data`, that has a `query` property with a route.

```
React.createClass({
  mixins: [myMixin],
  data: {
    query: "/api/foo"
  },
  componentDidUpdate(): function(){
  }
  ...
}
```

On `componentDidMount` **inside the mixin**, it would query that route, get back the data and put it on state.

```
var myMixin = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount(): function(){
    this.fetchData(this.data.query)
  }
  fetchData(query) {
    // fetch the data
  }
  ...
}
```

This extracts a lot of boilerplate from my components. I don't have to run a `componentDidMount` on every component, just have the `data` object.

I have this mixin scattered all over the project. It actually does a lot more than this but I'm just trying to dumb it down for example sake.

In comes HOCs. I took the all the stuff from `data` and put in into `getInitialState`. Now that I have `data` on the now wrapped component's state, how do I access it? Like my mixin, I want my HOC to handle my `componentDidMount`, get access to `data.query` and fetch the data. I don't want to have to rewrite every component to have a `componentDidMount`.

PS- 
I normally use the newest version of React and ES6, if anyone can tell me why the mixin could do `this.data` and my component couldn't that would be very helpful. In the newest version of React you can't define an object outside of `render()` like that.

Comment: answering this would be easier if you're willing to post your HoC code

Comment: i disagree. if you cant answer this at the most basic level how can you answer it with added complexity

Comment: That's not really nice. Your question was fairly difficult to understand because of the way you wrote it. I took the time to read it and was trying to come up with a solution tailored towards you. If you want a vague answer: you can use any of the standard patterns where child components need to communicate with parent components. Pass things to children via props (you can pass your wrapper's state to the child as props). If your children need to communicate back to the parent, have the parent pass it a handler function.

Comment: Either reword your question so it's a little bit more clear what you're trying to get at or post some pseudo-code of your higher order component so that I can provide a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React doesn't encourage to change the `state` from outside of the component. The `state` is owned by component and so only the component has control over it.

From [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

> State is similar to props, but it is private and fully controlled by
>   the component.

So what you can do is use `props` instead of `state`. For the given example you can write Higher Order Component as follows. But your Child component should be altered to render data from `props` instead of `state`.

```
function HOC(WrappedComponent){

  return React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
      return { data: null };
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
      this.fetchData(WrappedComponent.prototype.data.query)
    },

    fetchData: function(query){
     // Fetching data first
     // Then set the state with data
     this.setState({data:data});
    },

    render: function() {
      var props = Object.assign({}, this.props, this.state);
      return React.createElement(WrappedComponent, props);
    }

  });

}

var HOCChild = HOC(Child);
```

> PS- I normally use the newest version of React and ES6, if anyone can
>   tell me why the mixin could do this.data and my component couldn't
>   that would be very helpful. In the newest version of React you can't
>   define an object outside of render() like that.

Usually, React Component define as an ES6 class. ES6 classes don't support static or instance properties. But you can define instance properties inside the contractor like this.

```
class A{
  constructor(){
    this.foo = "foo"
  }
}
```